# Cassandra + Fetch the last records using in query

Tags: node.js, cassandra

I am new in this cassandra database using with nodejs.

I have user_activity table. In this table data will insert based on user activity.

Also I have some user list. I need to fetch the data in that particular users and last record.

I don't interest to put the query in for loop. Have any other idea to achieve this?

Example Code:

```
var userlist = ["12", "34", "56"];
var query = 'SELECT * FROM user_activity WHERE userid IN ?';
server.user.execute(query, [userlist], {
    prepare : true
}, function(err, result) {
   console.log(results);
});
```

How to get the user lists for last one ?

Example:

```
user id = 12 - need to get last record;
user id = 34 - need to get last record;
user id = 56 - need to get last record;
```

I need to get these 3 records.
Table Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE test.user_activity (
    userid text,
    ts timestamp,
    clientid text,
    clientip text,
    status text,
    PRIMARY KEY (userid, ts)
)
```

Comment: Hello, can you provide some schema description ?

Comment: You want to get only last user details?

Comment: updated table schema @GuillaumeS

Comment: @abdulbarik - I want "12", "34", "56" this users last row details

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible if you use the `IN` filter.

If it is a single user_id filter you can apply order by.  Of course you need a column for inserted/updated time. So query will be like this:

```
SELECT * FROM user_activity WHERE user_id = 12 ORDER BY updated_at LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Its not a single. need to get multiple users last records.

Comment: then it is not possible in query. You must handle something in code level

Comment: It's possible to fetch the data using executeBatch ? ( I mean multiple select query in batch)

Comment: It looks like he does have a column for the time...`ts`.  And with your `ORDER BY` I assume you mean to have `DESC` on the end?

Comment: @RSKMR Its not possible even you user executeBatch in this case.

Comment: @Aaron ts  is the time to order the row and it should have DESC at the end. I just thrown a random query.

Answer (score 1):

You can put `N` value  to get number of records

```
SELECT * FROM user_activity WHERE userid IN ? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT N
```

Comment: I am expecting results to get each users last records.

Comment: my query does to get 3 records in your case if put it `3` and that will get last three records of that user which you have mentioned.Isn't?

Comment: No. Sorry if my content is clear means.  My question is need to get those 3 users (each and everyone) results of last records